# How can I show a minimal version of the react-calendar-timeline?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-calendar-timeline

I'm building a web app and would like to integrate the [react-calendar-timeline](https://github.com/namespace-ee/react-calendar-timeline) into it. I've never worked with React before but I have worked with Vue. Every option I try gives me a blank browser window, either with or without an error in the console. What I've tried:

**First try:**
I've created a new folder and used `npm install --save react-calendar-timeline` into it to install all peer dependencies. This creates a nodes_module package with the dependencies `react`, `react-dom`, `moment` and `interacsjs` (and a few more), this seems to work fine for me. Then I tried to create a javascript file (tried both `.js` and `.jsx`) with the code below, also stated under 'At the very minimum:' on the Github page of the library.

**index.js:**

```
import Timeline from 'react-calendar-timeline'
// make sure you include the timeline stylesheet or the timeline will not be styled
import 'react-calendar-timeline/lib/Timeline.css'
import moment from 'moment'

const groups = [{ id: 1, title: 'group 1' }, { id: 2, title: 'group 2' }]

const items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    group: 1,
    title: 'item 1',
    start_time: moment(),
    end_time: moment().add(1, 'hour')
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    group: 2,
    title: 'item 2',
    start_time: moment().add(-0.5, 'hour'),
    end_time: moment().add(0.5, 'hour')
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    group: 1,
    title: 'item 3',
    start_time: moment().add(2, 'hour'),
    end_time: moment().add(3, 'hour')
  }
]

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    Rendered by react!
    <Timeline
      groups={groups}
      items={items}
      defaultTimeStart={moment().add(-12, 'hour')}
      defaultTimeEnd={moment().add(12, 'hour')}
    />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

I've created a basic HTML file and created a script src to this `index.js` file from above.

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

This loads the `index.js` file but gives me an error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at index.js:1:1)`. So I added `type="module"` to the script link: `<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>` on line 7 in `index.js`. This gives me the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at index.js:33:3)`.

**Second try:**
I also saw on the github that there were some [examples](https://github.com/namespace-ee/react-calendar-timeline/tree/master/examples), so I tried one, the [Basic Usage](https://codesandbox.io/s/w6xvqzno4w) one. This is a link to a codesandbox.io, I've created files with the exact names and code as used in the example but don't know where to go from there. The `index.html` only has a div and if I open this file (either by just opening it or by opening it with a live server from VSC) nothing seems to happen. So I add the code from the `index.html` file from above to link to the `index.js` file in here. This opens the code from `index.js`, but gives me the exact error from above (the module one). So I add `type="module"` again and it then gives me the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at index.js:7:3)`, which again is the `<div>` opening tag.

What am I missing to create a minimal version of the `react-calendar-timeline`, so I can use it to create my own timeline afterwards?

Comment: What do you mean with minimal version?

Comment: @egemenakturk the most basic version that works; a test version; a 'Hello world' kind of timeline. Just so I can see the timeline works and then I can create something from it. Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't follow what you really asking. Sorry

Comment: @egemenakturk that's my bad then, sorry. You know how when you want to test a basic html/js webpage you link to the code and write `console.log("Hello world")` just to see if the code works? Well, in this case I'd like to make a calendar timeline which I can later fill with more data, but before I can do that I'd like to test to see if I can get a basic version of the library to work so I can expand on it. But I can't get that to work, which is why I'm asking. Hope this clarifies it!

Comment: Oh ok. When you say minimal version, I thought you were asking for minimal size :D